# Conversion helper with support for enumerations and Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, api, converting

I recently wrote this code as a more versatile stand-in for `Convert.ChangeType`. I have a nagging feeling that there's something I might be overlooking, or that there might be a more efficient algorithm for this.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns an object of type <typeparamref name="T"/> whose value is equivalent to that of the specified 
    ///     object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    ///     The output type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">
    ///     An object that implements <see cref="IConvertible"/> or is <see cref="Nullable{T}"/> where the underlying
    ///     type implements <see cref="IConvertible"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     An object whose type is <typeparamref name="T"/> and whose value is equivalent to <paramref name="value"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">
    ///     The specified value is not defined by the enumeration (when <typeparamref name="T"/> is an enum, or Nullable{T}
    ///     where the underlying type is an enum).
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidCastException"
    /// <remarks>
    ///     This method works similarly to <see cref="Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)"/> with the addition of support
    ///     for enumerations and <see cref="Nullable{T}"/> where the underlying type is <see cref="IConvertible"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    internal static T ChangeType<T>(object value) {

        Type type = typeof(T);
        Type underlyingNullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);

        if ((underlyingNullableType ?? type).IsEnum) {

            // The specified type is an enum or Nullable{T} where T is an enum.

            T convertedEnum = (T)Enum.ToObject(underlyingNullableType ?? type, value);

            if (!Enum.IsDefined(underlyingNullableType ?? type, convertedEnum)) {
                throw new ArgumentException("The specified value is not defined by the enumeration.", "value");
            }

            return convertedEnum;
        } else if (type.IsValueType && underlyingNullableType == null) {

            // The specified type is a non-nullable value type.

            if (value == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(value)) {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert a null value to a non-nullable type.");
            }

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        }

        // The specified type is a reference type or Nullable{T} where T is not an enum.
        return (value == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(value)) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingNullableType ?? type);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Doc Comments

Well done! I rarely see *a single method* so thoroughly documented with XML doc comments. There's a catch though. Be careful about just how much you do this. It can really obstruct the readability of the actual code. I count roughly ***20 lines*** of documentations here. Is all of that really necessary? I don't think it is.

For example:

> ```
> /// <typeparam name="T">
> ///     The output type.
> /// </typeparam>
> ```

That's..... useless. It's obvious. Don't document the obvious.

### Style

I don't know a C# dev on this site that doesn't prefer new line braces to the "Egyptian" style braces that you use. If you're working with others, I would recommend you stick with the "C# style", but really, it doesn't matter. You were 100% consistent and that is what *really* matters at the end of the day.

### Null Coalescence

> ```
> if ((underlyingNullableType ?? type).IsEnum) {
> ```

[image: WTFs per Minute]

I'm sorry, but wtf? How do you expect anyone to wrap their head around that?

Null Coalescence has a time and place. This  isn't it, and it's all over the place in this code. It's seriously harming readability/understandability.

I'll be clear about it. There's nothing wrong with `underlyingNullableType ?? type`, but once you put that inside of an `if` statement ***and*** call a method on it... it's.... meaningless. It becomes completely ungrokkable.

Comment: I agreed and I think for example: `Type currentType = (underlyingNullableType ?? type);` - would be a good start.

Comment: It would be a very good start I think @t3chb0t.

Answer (score 4):

```
/// <summary>
///     Returns an object of type <typeparamref name="T"/> whose value is equivalent to that of the specified 
///     object.
/// </summary>

...

/// <returns>
///     An object whose type is <typeparamref name="T"/> and whose value is equivalent to <paramref name="value"/>.
/// </returns>
```

I don't see any reason to repeat what was said in `<summary>` in `<returns>`. I wouldn't write `<returns>` here at all. (Unless you're writing a library with very high demands on documentation, like the .Net framework itself.)

---

```
underlyingNullableType ?? type
```

You're repeating this expression several times. You should probably extract it into a variable.

---

You should be consistent: either use `if`-`else if`-`else` and ignore the `return`s, or acknowledge the `return`s and use `if`-`if`-nothing.

Answer (score 3):

#### Review

- re-organize your code to avoid redundant code segments `underlyingNullableType ?? type` or `DBNull.Value` checks
- I just found out you have a [follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74637/conversion-helper-with-support-for-enumerations-and-nullablet-the-remix): pitty I didn't notice it before :) That one is also review-worthy / can be improved

#### Bugs

- `if (!Enum.IsDefined(..` should not be called. [Microsoft Policy: Why is a non defined enum value allowed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66ac3c72-6af1-4967-afd3-734980adde9a/why-is-a-non-defined-enum-value-allowed?forum=netfxbcl)
- Your method throws an `ArgumentException` when dealing with enums with different underlying types

Additional reason why you can't use `Enum.IsDefined`: suppose we have the following enum..

```
[Flags]
enum A : uint
{
    None = 0,
    X = 1,
    Y = 2
}
```

Conversion fails because of not defined, even though `A.X | A.Y` is perfectly valid.

#### Refactored code

To be honest, I had to completely rewrite the flow to get rid of the redundant code blocks. First check the edge case when `value` is `null`. Then extract a `nonNullableType` to continue to work with. Process the other edge case with `Enum` and its underlying type. Use the exiting API `Convert.ChangeType` to map the normal cases. I have made some inline comments to explain what I'm doing.

```
public static T ChangeType<T>(object value)
{
    var isNull = IsNull(value);
    var type = typeof(T);

    if (isNull)
    {
        if (!type.IsNullAssignable())
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot cast null to {type}");
        }

        // null-assignable types (reference types and nullable types) can deal with null
        return default;
    }

    // use this type from here on to avoid the redundant 'if nullable .. else ..'
    var nonNullableType = type.AsNonNullable();

    if (nonNullableType.IsEnum)
    {
        // convert the value to the underlying type of the enum and
        // convert that result to the enum
        var enumUnderlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(nonNullableType);
        var enumUnderlyingValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, enumUnderlyingType);
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(nonNullableType, enumUnderlyingValue);
    }

    // let .NET handle remaining convertions
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, nonNullableType);
}

public static bool IsNull(object value)
{
    // - value == null uses the type's equality operator (usefull for Nullable)
    // - ReferenceEquals checks for actual null references
    // - DBNull is a special null value

    return value == null 
        || ReferenceEquals(null, value)
        || value is DBNull;
}
```

Helper class

*argument checks are left out for brevity*

```
public static class TypeExtension
{
    public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
    }

    public static bool IsNullAssignable(this Type type)
    {
        return IsNullable(type) || !type.IsValueType;
    }

    public static Type AsNonNullable(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsNullable() ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) : type;
    }
}
```

#### Use Cases / Tests

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConversions()
{
    // Positive tests

    var enumFlags = ChangeType<A>(A.X | A.Y);
    var enumFlagsUnderlying = ChangeType<A>(4);
    var enumFlagsUnderlyingDifferentType = ChangeType<A>(4d);
    var enumFlagsNullable = ChangeType<A?>(A.X | A.Y);
    var enumFlagsNullableNull = ChangeType<A?>(null);
    var enumFlagsNullableDBNull = ChangeType<A?>(DBNull.Value);
    var referenceType = ChangeType<RefType>(null);
    var valueType = ChangeType<ValType>(default(ValType));
    var valueTypeNullable = ChangeType<ValType?>(default(ValType));
    var valueTypeNullableNull = ChangeType<ValType?>(null);
    var enumTypeWithDifferentUnderlyingTypes = ChangeType<A>(B.Z);
    var enumTypeWithDifferentUnderlyingTypesWithoutConstant = ChangeType<A>(B.ZZ);

    // Negative tests

    Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidCastException>(() => ChangeType<ValType>(null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the standard C# bracing style

```
if (Condition)
{
    //Operations
}
```

instead of the Java Style bracing you have in your code, it makes it read funny.

Comment: As a C# dev, I agree with this, but I will point out that it looks like OP was consistent. And really, consistency is more important than which style braces he chose.

Comment: @RubberDuck I agree.